# Why last hydrated element is passed by reference in doctrine2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I use the Doctrine 2.3.1-DEV version.

Last fetched element is passed by reference. Why?

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$rows = $em->getRepository('FMECoreBundle:TheListGridRow')
->createQueryBuilder('row')
->getQuery()
->getArrayResult();
var_dump($rows);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["rank"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(6)
    ["rank"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  &array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["rank"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

Why last element is `&array(2)`? Who can explain?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Could you open an issue for it?

Comment: I created the ticket: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2178